# I keep getting SQL Error (1064): right syntax to use near '10)' with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I first run this Query to `INSERT` a row

```
INSERT INTO a (acol, bcol, ccol) VALUES (1, 1, 12);
```

Then I follow it with

```
INSERT INTO a (acol, bcol, ccol) VALUES (1, 1, 12) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol=VALUES(10);
```

while having `UNIQUE KEY` on `aco, bcol`, But I keep getting this error:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near '10)' at line 1
```

Now I tried it at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/713eae/1) and got this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO a (acol, bcol, ccol) VALUES (1, 1, 12) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol=' at line 3
```

after adding it.

What is the problem with my Query?

Comment: You have no `10)` in your query so I suspect that the error might be from a trigger.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, my mistake, wrote it `5` here instead of `10`

Comment: What are you trying to do here `ccol=VALUES(10)`?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel update the column `ccol` with the value `10`

Comment: Why using `VALUES(5)` instead of a mere `5`

Comment: @Alfabravo I'm using `PDO` and insert it like this `ccol = VALUES(:ccol)` which gives me the same error, Do i just write `ccol = :ccol`?

Comment: @Toleo try and see if you get the expected result :)

Comment: @Alfabravo oh, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VALUES()` in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part is used to refer to columns from the `INSERT` part.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO a (acol, bcol, ccol) VALUES (1, 1, 12) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol = VALUES(ccol);
```

`VALUES(ccol)` will refer to the value of `ccol` which you tried to insert. It's `12` in this case.

If you just want to set a constant value, then just use

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol = 10
```

You can can also mix it and do something like

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol = VALUES(ccol) - 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

When using On Duplicate KEY UPDATE, use VALUES() only when you need the value of a column. For assigning numbers, it should be assigned without using VALUES() 
`INSERT INTO a1 (acol, bcol, ccol) VALUES (1, 1, 12) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol`= 5;

Answer (score 1):

use 
`INSERT INTO a (acol, bcol, ccol) VALUES (1, 1, 12) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ccol=10;`